# To make an background images autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, content-management-system, elementor

I've been trying to make a slider with the functionality of hover on Icon the background images should be changed. I've achieved this thing but One more thing to be add-in this slider that the background images also should be autoplay.

I've made this slider in WordPress project using Elementor and made the custom Slider using javascript dom manipulation.

How can I achieve both things like first autoplay the background images and also when anyone hovers on the icon the background image also should be changed?

JavaScript code for running the functionality of on icon hover to change the background image.

```
<script>



const backgroundChange = document.querySelector('#hero-section');

const icon1 = document.querySelector('.icon-1');

icon1.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    backgroundChange.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://webchargers.in/ghc/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/first-slide.png)'
});

const icon2 = document.querySelector('.icon-2');

icon2.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    backgroundChange.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://webchargers.in/ghc/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/second-slide-1.png)'
});


const icon3 = document.querySelector('.icon-3');

icon3.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    backgroundChange.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://webchargers.in/ghc/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/third-slide.png)'
});

const icon4 = document.querySelector('.icon-4');

icon4.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    backgroundChange.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://webchargers.in/ghc/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/fourth-slide.png)'
});

const icon5 = document.querySelector('.icon-5');

icon5.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    backgroundChange.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://webchargers.in/ghc/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/fifth-slide.png)'
});

const icon6 = document.querySelector('.icon-6');

icon6.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    backgroundChange.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://webchargers.in/ghc/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/sixth-slide.png)'
});


backgroundChange.style.autoPlay = 'true';





</script>

<style>
#hero-section{
transition: background 0.4s linear;
}





</style>
```

Comment: Since you didn't provide a min-working example it's hard to imagine how this is supposed to look like and

Answer (score 0):

Solution is,- have autoplay image links array, then with `setTimeout()` make an infinite loop where you will change element background image from that array. As long as someone hovers onto background - set custom background image and set autoplay boolean mode to `false`. Something like :

```html
<H2 style="color:cyan">Hover mouse to switch-off autoplay and change background</H2>
<script>
var images = ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Midland_4-2-2_No._673_Rainhill_1980_%E2%80%93_edited.jpg',
'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/ArcodelaMacarena.jpg/800px-ArcodelaMacarena.jpg'
];
var ix = 0;
var autoplay = true;

function loop(pause=2000) {
      setTimeout(function () {
          if (autoplay) {
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[ix]}')`;
            ix = (ix+1)%images.length;
          }
          loop();
      }, pause);
}

document.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {
  autoplay = false;
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Witton_Lakes_-_Lower_%28448543147%29.jpg/1024px-Witton_Lakes_-_Lower_%28448543147%29.jpg')`;
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {
  autoplay = true;
}, false);

loop(0);

</script>
```